# Where to obtain wholesale hardware for a custom router?

Tags: hardware

I am starting a project for a client and I would like to know if there is a place to obtain hardware to base a custom router/network appliance on.

I have the need for a rack mount device, something along the lines of the forfactor of the [smoothwall](http://www.smoothwall.net/live/index.php)  appliance.  I can't imagine that smoothwall (and countless others) are going to direct manufactures there has to be some wholesaler somewhere.

I also have the need for smaller 'remote' boxes that I am thinking I can use some sort of Mini-ITX form factor, but I am having troubling finding boards with dual and 1000Mbs ports.

So my questions are:

1. What are some wholesale places to purchase 'appliance type' hardware?
2. Does anyone know of any other alternative to the mini-itx form factor to have dual nics and/or 1Gbs port(s)?

Comment: Seems that [PortWell](http://www.portwell.com/products/ca.asp) has exactly the kind of things I was asking for; however they require a quote and I would prefer a shop that will sell One-Offs.   However I *really* like the devices with LCDs

Comment: http://www.balticnetworks.com/ has some interesting offerings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point it looks like NewEgg is my best bet for raw hardware....

Or anyther vendor such as Zareason if I would like (linux) support /w warranty.

Answer (score 2):

We use SuperMicro 1U Atom based devices as our routers. Specifically the [SuperServer 5015A-PHF](http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1U/5015/SYS-5015A-PHF.cfm). In the past we used the [SuperServer 5015A-H](http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1U/5015/SYS-5015A-H.cfm?typ=H)

They are available via BellMicro or IngramMicro

Answer (score 1):

Most appliances are just Dell or HP servers with a custom faceplate on them.  If you just need a small 1U server check out some of the things that Dell offers.  Then have a print shop make a large sticker that you can put over the faceplate.  It won't be as nice as a customer face place, but it will be MUCH cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into supply chain 101, you'll have a hard time finding a wholesaler who's willing to sell you the device you're looking for in quantities less than 100 (or 1000, or 10,000, etc.).  If you mean you want a *whitebox* network device, you have some options mentioned already (SuperMicro, Portwell, Dell, etc.).

Netgate.com also sells a rack-mounted (or desktop configuration) [Hamakua](http://store.netgate.com/Netgate-Hamakua-1U-P229C61.aspx) device I've been very happy with: it is very well built and with 5 GbE NICs, 1GHz Celeron and up to 2GB DDR2 RAM, you can push some pretty serious packets with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of any other alternative to the mini-itx form factor to have dual nics 
>   and/or 1Gbs port(s)?

Just about all the miniITX motherboards I've looked at recently have 1 Gbps ethernet.

Comment: Mikrotik 450 or 750. Smaller, 5 ethernet ports, router OS. Cost is LOW. Can do a lot, including BGP.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.linnitx.com. I would at this point go with something - unless you need a LOT of performance - something from MIKROTIK (a RouterBoard). If this fails, go for a 1" rack item for RouterOS. Unless you go really commercial (i.e. Cisco, Extreme Networks etc.) that seems to be the best implementation of a routing operating system for a decent price.